# Add multiple rows in PHP function

Tags: php, mysql

Basically i want to add "price" into the data table. how can i do that?
the "price" has been added to the database.

Form:

```
    <form action="main/insertRow" method="post">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="text" />
    <label>Price:</label>
    <input type="text" name="price" />
    <input type="submit" value="Add" />
    </form>
```

Function:

```
    public function insertRow($data) {
    $sth = $this -> db -> onlyExecute('INSERT INTO data (`text`) VALUES (:data)', array(':data' => $data));
    if ($sth) {
        echo true;
    } else {
        echo false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you look https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp Check that INSERT example. If your `$data` parameter is `text` field, then you should add new parametenr $price and pass it to function first. Then modify INSERT clause. 

If I understant the question right. So you really mean how to insert multiple columns? Not rows?

Comment: What have you tried so far? We want to help you find a solution, but do not want to do your work for you.

Answer (score 0):

What is inside 'onlyExecute' function? Are you sure that your $data is not null in 'insertRow' function?
If it's a PDO you can doing that:

```
$sth = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO data (`text`) VALUES (:data)');
$sth->execute([':data' => $data]);
```

or

```
$sth = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO data (`text`) VALUES (:data)');
$sth->bindValue(':data', $data);
$sth->execute();
```

Also make sure that your $data is a string, if it is an array you need to type $data['your_key']